# Need to convert char* (pointer) to wchar_t* (pointer)

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, char, wchar-t

I am doing some serial port communcation to a computer controlled pump and the createfile function I used to communicate requires the com port name to be parsed as a wchar_t pointer.

I am also using QT to create a form and aquire the com port name as a QString.

This QString is converted to a char array and pointed to as follows:

```
   char* Dialog::GetPumpSerialPortNumber(){
   QString mystring;
   mystring = ui->comboBox_2->currentText();
   char * mychar;
   mychar = mystring.toLatin1().data();
   return mychar;
```

I now need to set my port number which is stored as a wchar_t* in my pump object. I do this by calling the following function:

```
   void pump::setPortNumber(wchar_t* portNumber){
       this->portNumber = portNumber;
   }
```

Thus how do I change my char* (mychar) into a wchar_t* (portNumber)?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a potential memory problem with your function, it returns a pointer to memory inside a temporary variable (the result of toLatin1());

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about just needing a char array to a wchar_t array, here's a solution for you:

```
static wchar_t* charToWChar(const char* text)
{
    size_t size = strlen(text) + 1;
    wchar_t* wa = new wchar_t[size];
    mbstowcs(wa,text,size);
    return wa;
}
```

Comment: mbstowcs is quite obsolete.. but it works.
BTW I have found nice MSDN article that shows converting between various string. Look to my answer for details..

Comment: but this might waste some memory as strlen will count the chars byte by byte and not how many wchars you will need. Check my answer and correct me if I'm wrong as I'm new to this topic.

Comment: @Naheel That assumes the char* contains wide characters. If the char* is simply a string of ascii character that aren't padded for a wchar string and you want it to be, then this is what you would use. If you want to get the length of a wchar string you should use wcslen instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

An enhancement to leetNightshade's answer could be

```
size_t unistrlen(const char *s) {
    size_t sz = 0;
    const char *sc;
    for (sc = s; *sc != '\0'; sc+=(
        ((*sc&0x80)==0x80) ? 2 :/*1st byte of 2-byte character*/
        ((*sc&0xc0)==0xc0) ? 3 :/*1st byte of 3-byte character*/
        ((*sc&0xe0)==0xe0) ? 4 :/*1st byte of 4-byte character*/
        ((*sc&0xf0)==0xf0) ? 1 :/*2nd, 3rd, or 4th byte of multi-byte character*/
                             1) /*single byte character*/)
        if ((*sc&0xf0)!=0xf0) sz++;
    return sz;
} 

wchar_t* charToWChar(const char* text) {
    size_t size = unistrlen(text) + 1;
    wchar_t* wa = new wchar_t[size];
    mbstowcs(wa,text,size);
    return wa;
}
```

Where unistrlen will return how many characters (single or multi bytes characters) in your string unlike strlen which returns the length byte by byte and that might waste some memory if your string contains some multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`toWCharArray`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html#toWCharArray) function of `QString` to have your wchar_t* value and return a wchar_t* from your `GetPumpSerialPortNumber` function.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a helpful article in MSDN - [How to: Convert Between Various String Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/how-to-convert-between-various-string-types?view=vs-2019). I guess it should be useful.

Comment: Link is dead. Next time you should provide a copy of the valid section of code here, for exactly this case.

Comment: @leetNightshade Links was dead, but Google isn't. I've corrected the link. I don't remember precisely a context of my answer, so correct the link without inserting of code.

Answer (score -1):

[`QString::toWCharArray ( wchar_t * array )`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html#toWCharArray) ?

Comment: I'm clearly doing something wrong my code:    

wchar_t* Dialog::GetPumpSerialPortNumber(){
   QString mystring;
   mystring = ui->comboBox_2->currentText();
   wchar_t * mycharPointer;
   wchar_t mychar[mystring.size()];
   mychar[mystring.size()-1] = '\n';
   mystring.toWCharArray(mychar);
   mycharPointer = mychar;
   cout << *mycharPointer;
   return mycharPointer;
}

seems to return an address rather than the char array to "COM6"